# VBA email loop and Outlook Text formatting error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Sorry if it's more of a Superuser.com question, but I don't know if I have an Outlook or VBA code issue.

I have a `Windows 10` + `Office365` PC running `Excel VBA` loops to send out emails with `Outlook`. The amount is a few hundred emails a night (with a few second intervals) and it has been running fine for well over a year without any meaningful change to VBA code. Only significant change has been turning `Cached Exchange Mode` **ON** in Outlook. Otherwise just regular Windows + Office365 updates.

Without any logical pattern, I have started to get a random VBA error which quits the loop like this:

[image]

Piece of VBA has been something simple such the snippet below (in this case I'm adding Excel range to email body, but most of them doesn't have even that, but just more HTML-formatted text):

```
Set rng = myTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = "receiver1@mydomain.com; receiver1@mydomain.com"
    .Subject = "MYTEXT1 " & Date
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "sharedmailbox@mydomain.com"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .send
End With

Set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
```

Some things to point out:

1. VBA code crashes at `.Display` - if I run Debug, restart Outlook (Outlook is still responsive), and resume VBA code execution at `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` - loop always continues to execute. Doing this without Outlook restart takes me back to the same VBA error
2. The "few hundred a night" emails is over several different Excel workbooks and different VBA subs, though with very similar syntax and I run them with VBScript in sequence. I added a call to PowerShell script within VBScript to restart Outlook between each workbook is processed. This seemingly improved the situation somewhat, but clearly didn't fix the issue entirely. I might also try something like "restart Outlook after every 50 emails" inside the VBA, however I feel like it's the wrong way to solve this.
3. I tried Office Online Repair with no success.

Any suggestions on what to try? Are there smarter approaches to re-installing the entire system?

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspects when automation Outlook for sending emails from other Office applications:

1. There is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` each time you need to send an email. So, the following line of code can put outside of the procedure of sending emails:

   ```
   Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   ```
2. There is no need to display a newly created item before calling the `Send` method. The only reason could be is to get the signature generated, but anyway, it is overwritten when you set the `HTMLBody` property in the code:

   ```
   With OutMail
      .To = "receiver1@mydomain.com; receiver1@mydomain.com"
      .Subject = "MYTEXT1 " & Date
      .SentOnBehalfOfName = "sharedmailbox@mydomain.com"
      .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
      .Send
   End With
   ```

   Don't forget that `Send` method has a capital letter if it makes sense. VBA is not case sensitive, but anyway.
3. You may face with a standard security issue when Outlook is automated from any external application when unsafe properties and methods are used in the code.

   To deal with a safe `Application` object and the entire the Outlook object model you need to develop a COM add-in which can be running along with the host application. In that case you can use standard .net framework techniques for connecting two applications together, for example, .net remoting and etc.

   To avoid security issues you can:

   1. Use a low-level API which doesn't trigger issues/dialogs in Outlook - Extended MAPI or any third-party wrappers around that API such as Redemption.
   2. Use third party components that suppress such issues/dialog in Outlook, for example, see https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php.
   3. Develop a COM add-in which can have access to the trusted `Application` object.
   4. Install any AV with latest updates.
   5. Use GPO to set up settings to not trigger security issues/dialogs.

   Read more about that in the ["A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf" warning in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/security/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-email-message-on-your-behalf) article.